# Reading multiple csv files and merging them into one using Apache Beam

Tags: python, pandas, apache-beam

I am trying to build a pipeline that reads several files locally from a directory `path` using `MatchFiles` and merges those files into one `csv` file by applying `pd.concat` through `class merge_dataframes (beam.DoFn)` like following:

```
class merge_dataframes(beam.DoFn):
def process(self, element, ):
    logging.info(element)
    logging.info(type(element))
    yield pd.concat(element).reset_index(drop=True)


path = 'concats/yellow_tripdata_*.csv'
output = Path('/output_tests/')
p = beam.Pipeline()

concating = (p
             | beam.io.fileio.MatchFiles('concats/*.csv')
             | beam.io.fileio.ReadMatches()
             | beam.ParDo(merge_dataframes())
             | beam.io.WriteToText(str(output), file_name_suffix='.csv'))
p.run()
```

However, when I execute the pipeline, as an output an empty file is generated. Any suggestions on this...

Let's say that the folder `path` has three files: `yellow_tripdata_1.csv`, `yellow_tripdata_2.csv` and `yellow_tripdata_3.csv`

Comment: Doesn't look like Windows can eat `output_tests/` as a path. Try using Windows format. Better yet, try using `pathlib.Path` that is OS agnostic. Then, see if `beam` accepts that type. Otherwise, call `str` on the `pathlib.Path` object before sending it as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @edd. I have used pathlib.Path "output = Path('output_tests/')" and applied to 'beam.io.WriteToText(str(output), file_name_suffix='.csv')'. The error is fixed but I still not getting the merged file, rather getting an empty output.

Comment: Did you do the same with the input, `MatchFiles`? Did you try absolute paths? Other than that, I'm not familiar with `beam`

Comment: Yes, did the same with the input. I also tried absolute paths. Still the same thing...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating multiple csv files in Apache Beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70520233/concatenating-multiple-csv-files-in-apache-beam)