# Concatenating multiple csv files in Apache Beam

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to read several `csv` files using `fileio.MatchFiles` converting them into `pd.DataFrame` then later concatenating them into one `csv` file. To perform this, I have created two `ParDo` classes to covert files into DataFrame and then merge them into `merged csv`. The whole snippet looks like below:

```
class convert_to_dataFrame(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        return pd.DataFrame(element)

class merge_dataframes(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        logging.info(element)
        logging.info(type(element))
        return pd.concat(element).reset_index(drop=True)

p = beam.Pipeline() 
concating = (p
             | beam.io.fileio.MatchFiles("C:/Users/firuz/Documents/task/mobilab_da_task/concats/**")
             | beam.io.fileio.ReadMatches()
             | beam.Reshuffle()
             | beam.ParDo(convert_to_dataFrame())
             | beam.combiners.ToList()
             | beam.ParDo(merge_dataframes())
             | beam.io.WriteToText('C:/Users/firuz/Documents/task/mobilab_da_task/output_tests/merged', file_name_suffix='.csv'))

p.run()
```

After running I receive an `ValueError` on `ParDO(merge_dataframes)`. I presume that `ReadMatches` doesn't allocate any file or `ParDo(convert_to_dataFrame)` returning None objects. Any ideas on this approach or any other approaches on reading and merging files.
The Error output:

> ValueError: No objects to concatenate [while running
> 'ParDo(merge_dataframes)']

Comment: WriteToText already concats lines in files, if you want just one, you can add "nun_shards=1", but note this reduce parallelism.

Comment: Also, the combiner, reshuffle and probably the two pardos can be removed

Comment: thank you for your comment @Iñigo. The thing is that `MatchFiles` does not match files, so `ReadMatches` doesn't read any file. I tried to create a for loop over ReadFromText like  `datasets = [] for i, file in enumerate(input):     reading = (p 
 beam.io.ReadFromText(file, skip_header_lines=1)) datasets.append(reading)`. But stuck into an RuntimeRrror `untimeError: A transform with label "ReadFromText" already exists in the pipeline`

Comment: You are on a windows file system,  you need to use the  delimiter “ \” and not “ /”. You can use “os.path.join”  instead, and you do not need to worry about the filesystem.

Comment: Oh, right, you need `ReadAllFromText` instead of `ReadMatches`

Comment: @RaulSaucedo thanks. added your suggestion as `beam.io.fileio.MatchFiles(os.path.join(path)+"**.csv")`. Now it matches the files but have still error with convert_to_dataFrame() `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! [while running 'ParDo(convert_to_dataFrame)']`

Comment: @Firuz If this answer helped you, you can upvote or accept the answer. This can help future users who are having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question regarding the error `ValueError: No objects to concatenate [while running 'ParDo(merge_dataframes)'],` you are on a Windows file system, and you need to use the delimiter  `\` instead of  `/`. You can use `os.path.join` instead, and you do not need to worry about the filesystem:

```
import os 
all_files1 = glob.glob(os.path.join(path1, "*.csv"))
```

For the second question regarding the error `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! [while running 'ParDo(convert_to_dataFrame)'],` you are sending another type of value of a dict to the DataFrame constructor, and not a dict itself. This is the reason why you get that error.

You could do this:

```
DataFrame(eval(data))
```